# Как работает "reflect" в HLSL?

Tags: unity3d, шейдеры

При написании specular-части шейдера столкнулся с проблемой:
при использовании функции *reflect(...)* внутри PixelShader возникла проблема с интерполяцией данных - картинка напоминала шейдинг Гуро:

```
ref = reflect( -_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz, input.worldNormal);
```

[image: шейдинг Гуро]

Я долго мучился с этой проблемой, пока наконец то не забил формулу напрямую - и тогда картинка получилось правильной:

```
float NdotL = dot(input.worldNormal, -_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
float3 ref = normalize(-_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - 2.0 * input.worldNormal * NdotL);
```

[image: правильная]

В чем проблема? В документации я не нашел каких либо объяснений по этому поводу: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3dhlsl/dx-graphics-hlsl-reflect

**Update**: Может быть моя видеокарта не поддерживает что то и компилятор оптимизирует? Она у меня достаточно старая - GTX GeForce 640m

**Update**: Выкладываю листинг шейдера

```
Shader "Unlit/Test/PBR Shader"
{
    SubShader
    {

        Pass
        {
            Tags {"LightMode" = "ForwardBase"}
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"
            #include "UnityLightingCommon.cginc" // for _LightColor0

            struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3 worldNormal : NORMAL0;
                float3 worldViewDirection : TEXCOORD1;
            };

            v2f vert(appdata_base input)
            {
                v2f output;
                output.pos = UnityObjectToClipPos(input.vertex);
                float3 worldPos = mul(unity_ObjectToWorld, input.vertex).xyz;
                output.worldNormal = normalize(UnityObjectToWorldNormal(input.normal));
                output.worldViewDirection = normalize(_WorldSpaceCameraPos.xyz - worldPos.xyz);
                return output;
            }

            fixed4 frag(v2f input) : SV_Target
            {
                fixed4 color = float4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

                //calculate reflection
                float NdotL = dot(input.worldNormal, -_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz);
                float3 ref = normalize(-_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz - 2.0 * input.worldNormal * NdotL);
                //just delete next "//"
                //ref = reflect(-_WorldSpaceLightPos0.xyz, input.worldNormal);

                //I dont use the diff component specifically
                float3 spec = pow(max(dot(input.worldViewDirection, ref), 0.0f), 32.0f);                
                color.xyz = spec;
                return color;
            }

                ENDCG
            }
    }
}
```

Я также столкнулся с этой проблемой в PBR shadere. В нем как выходные параметры вершинного шейдера я использовал следующие данные:

```
struct v2f
            {
                float4 pos : SV_POSITION;
                float3 worldNormal : NORMAL0;
                float3 WorldViewDir : TEXCOORD1;
                float3 worldPos : POSITION1;
            };
```

По идее, они должны интерполироваться и расчет должен выполняться по пикселю\фрагменту, но выход уж **очень** сильно похож на vertex shading. Я все еще думаю, что проблема может быть в оптимизации и т.п.
Также отмечу, что я использовал DirectxLight источник света. Один. Render Mode Auto/Important - выход один и тот же.

Comment: может дело в том, что Вы передаете в функцию `reflect` положение источника света со знаком минус, а не направление луча, который хотите отразить?

Comment: Я использую DirectLight и в данном случае это падающий луч(учитывая знак -). Также, в любом случае, в документации указана формула, которая должна быть эквивалентна функции. Переменные совпадают, так что результат должен быть один и тот же. 
И, по моему, это все таки слишком похоже на vertex shading, чтобы быть чем то другим.
Edit: Я столкнулся с этой же проблемой в PBR шейдере, где я не использую reflect. Или у меня косяк где-то в основе, или тут что то явно не так)

Answer (score 1):

В обоих случаях проблема была в том, что я не нормализовал вектора нормалей, интерполированные в вершинном шейдере.
Более подробно об интерполяции можно прочитать тут:
https://stanford.edu/class/ee267/lectures/lecture3.pdf